# SQL Server ODBC issue, what causes this error and how do I fix it?

Tags: sql-server

I have a old SQL Server database that I inherited, I did not have anything to do with design or development.  It has been working fine for years.  It uses a Access Front end, I am being asked to support a problem that has come up. This database has many functions, it is kind of a ERP or MRP system.  The access front end that I am being asked to support does not input anything, only outputs a report.
When the report runs, it issues the error pictured below.

[ODBC Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdu4W.jpg)

I have narrowed the error to an append query that is caused by 1 field in 1 table of the SQL database,  When I view that table in the SQL Server Management Studio, I received the error when I return all rows.  If I only return the top 10000 rows, there is not error.  It is therefore my conclusion that the error is a result of some "Corrupt" data in the table?  Can anyone make any suggestions as to how to solve this issue?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Write a query to find the corrupt data and then decide what to do with it. `try_convert` might be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that "R -1" is not a numeric value. Access was apparently expecting it to be treatable as an int.

Comment: So the data is not really corrupt it's just unexpected and unhandled. The error likely has nothing to do with ODBC either.

Comment: Dale K, Sorry about the inclusion of the image.  I thought I read that you could post error messages.  Will not do so in the future.  Can you suggest sql for a access query to eliminate the issue or should I do this using SQL Server Management Studio?  I do not have a large set of skills in SQL Server Management Studio.  Can probably do it in access though.

Comment: That error comes directly from SQL Server. The column being queried (you need to identify which one) contains the value `R - 1` and is an `nvarchar` column (text/string). You need to identify this row with a direct query `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourCol = 'R - 1'` then decide what to do with it: delete it, modify it, or modify the original query to ignore it

Comment: _When I view that table_ Selecting all rows from a table should not cause any sort of "conversion error" - there must be something special about the table (or your approach to selecting all rows) that you need to investigate further. Perhaps start by posting DDL for the table.

Comment: @SMor It actually is possible, if using computed columns https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=081bcdf35dc646f42690d8822f7170f2

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that reproduces your issue:

```sql
-- INT has higher data type precedence than (n)varchar
declare @Filter int = 25;

declare @t table (
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Val varchar(50) not null
);

insert into @t (Val)
values
    ('25'), ('27'), ('R - 1')
;

-- No issues
select * from @t;

-- Top (1) without reaching the problematic row
select top (1) *, 'First Match' as [Scenario]
from @t t
where t.Val = @Filter
order by t.Id;

-- Filtering full table - problem, "R - 1" cannot be converted to int
select *, 'All Matches' as [Scenario]
from @t t
where t.Val = @Filter
order by t.Id;
```

This kind of error happens when you use filtering parameters of wrong data types, compared to columns they are filtering. SQL Server won't tell you about incompatibility, trying instead to perform implicit conversions. In some cases it will work, for example if you have a `varchar` column with all values in it being integers. However, because it's text, anything can be put into it, even values that cannot be converted to `int`. The error will be raised only if SQL Server reaches the value it can't convert - in all other cases you won't notice anything.

Why SQL Server tries to convert string to integer, and not the other way around? It follows [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) rules, which define conversion direction for all implicit conversions (whenever a parameter type doesn't match the column it filters, or 2 columns on both sides of a join don't quite match each other).

In your case, you need to make sure that your parameters always match the data types of the columns they are applied to. If there are no parameters involved, like a `select * from dbo.MyTable`, then you need to check for computed columns - the incompatibility might reside there. Lastly, it might not be a table but a view - review its code and try to eliminate implicit conversions.

Comment: It turns out that what I thought was a table in my query is actually a view.  I don't know anything about views.  If I use the the SQL Server management Studio  to write a query like "Select * from dbo.vw_parts where Quote_Line = 'R - 1'" ,I get the same error.  I don't know how to isolate the troublesome record(s)

Comment: You can find the view in the Object Explorer in SSMS, script it from there and look at its code. Either update your question by adding the view code, or ask a new one.